# Java doing arithmetic using variable operators

Tags: java

ok so the variable `current` is an operator ( +-*/%)

and `t1 = stack.pop()` is a number in String formation
`t2 = stack.pop()` is a number in String formation also

I need to carry out the mathematical operation `t2 current t1` (t2 "operator" t1, basically)

How would you go about this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Comment: Have you tried anything? Convert the strings to `int`s or `float`s or whatever, determine which operator it is using `String.equals` and perform the operation,.

Comment: `+` is operator and `"+"` is a string. `t2 current t1` wrong and `t2 + t1` is correct when you want o concat the string `t2` and `t1`. For add the numbers in the strings you have to first convert the strings to numbers and add.

Comment: convert the numeric strings to numbers `Double.parseDouble(String)` and do a series of `if` statements to find value of operator `if(Strings.equal("*",operator))` etc.

Comment: Thanks guys, I had done it as the answer provided below suggested, I just wanted to know if there was another way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something simple :

```
enum operation {
    SUM,
    SUB,
    DIV,
    MUL,
}

static String performOperation(operation op, String t1, String t2) {
   // parse t1 & t2 into integers or whatever you use
   switch(op) {
   case SUM:
       //do sum
       break;
   case SUB:
       //do substraction
       break;

   // handle all of them....

}
```